# Sympy series with both x and log(x) - logx argument of sympy.series.gruntz.calculate_series

Tags: python, sympy

I'd like to expand an expression involving one variable `x` (which is assumed to be small). The expansion will involve terms which are polynomial in `x` and also terms which are polynomial in `log(x)`. Example:

```
(log(x/(1-x)))^2 = log(x)^2 + 2 x log(x) + x^2 log(x) + x^2 + ....
```

I didn't find a way to do this with sympy, but something tells me it might be possible because if I look at the source of sympy/series/gruntz.py and look for the function `calculate_series` I [find](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/58e1e9abade7c38c66871fd06bf76ebac8c1df78/sympy/series/gruntz.py#L466-L484):

```
def calculate_series(e, x, logx=None):
    """ Calculates at least one term of the series of "e" in "x".
    This is a place that fails most often, so it is in its own function.
    """
    ...
    ...
```

What does the `logx` argument mean here? It might be related to what I'd like to do but I'm not sure. I was experimenting a bit:

```
from sympy import log
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
e=log(x/(1-x))**2
for term in e.lseries(x,logx=y):
    print term
```

and this gives

```
y**2
```

which is correct as far as the log is concerned by itself but doesn't output the polynomial terms in `x` and the mixed terms with both `log(x)` and `x`.

Answer (score 0):

I just found it:

```
from sympy import log
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
e=log(x/(1-x))**2
print e.series(x,0,4,logx=y)
```

and this will give what I was after:

```
y**2 + 2*x*y + x**2*(y + 1) + x**3*(2*y/3 + 1) + O(x**4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of sympy you are using but I get:

```
In [60]: x = Symbol('x') 
    ...: y = Symbol('y') 
    ...: e = log(x/(1-x))**2 
    ...: s = e.series(x,0,4)                                                                                                                   

In [61]: s                                                                                                                                     
Out[61]: 
   2                    2 ⎛  1         1   ⎞    2       3 ⎛   2          1   ⎞    2       ⎛ 4⎞
log (x) + 2⋅x⋅log(x) + x ⋅⎜────── + ───────⎟⋅log (x) + x ⋅⎜──────── + ───────⎟⋅log (x) + O⎝x ⎠
                          ⎜log(x)      2   ⎟              ⎜3⋅log(x)      2   ⎟                
                          ⎝         log (x)⎠              ⎝           log (x)⎠                

In [62]: expand(s)                                                                                                                             
Out[62]: 
                                                3               
   2                    2    2           3   2⋅x ⋅log(x)    ⎛ 4⎞
log (x) + 2⋅x⋅log(x) + x  + x ⋅log(x) + x  + ─────────── + O⎝x ⎠
                                                  3             

In [63]: collect(expand(s), x)                                                                                                                 
Out[63]: 
   2                    2                 3 ⎛2⋅log(x)    ⎞    ⎛ 4⎞
log (x) + 2⋅x⋅log(x) + x ⋅(log(x) + 1) + x ⋅⎜──────── + 1⎟ + O⎝x ⎠
                                            ⎝   3        ⎠
```